# Random arithmetic overflows when reading from serial port

Tags: c#

What I'm doing is taking a user entered string, creating a packet with the data, then sending the string out to a serial port. I am then reading the data I send via a loopback connector. My send is working flawlessly, however my receive is randomly throwing an arithmetic overflow exception.

I say randomly because it is not happening consistently. For example, I send the message "hello" twice. The first time works fine, the second time outputs nothing and throws an exception. I restart my program, run the code again, and send hello only to receive "hell" and then an exception. On rare occasion, I'll receive the packet 3 or 4 times in a row without error before the exception.

Here is my relevant code:

```
public void receivePacket(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] tempByte = new byte[2];
    int byteCount = 0;

    while (serialPort1.BytesToRead > 0)
    {
        if (byteCount <= 1)
        {
            tempByte[byteCount] = (byte)serialPort1.ReadByte();
        }

        if (byteCount == 1)
        {
            receivedString = new byte[tempByte[byteCount]];
            receivedString[0] = tempByte[0];
            receivedString[1] = tempByte[1];
        }
        else if (byteCount > 1)
        {
            byte b = (byte)serialPort1.ReadByte();
            receivedString[byteCount] = b;
        }

        byteCount++; 

    }

    int strLen = (byteCount - 3);

    tempByte = new byte[strLen];

    int newBit = 0;

    for (int i = 2; i <= strLen+1; i++)
    {
        tempByte[newBit] = receivedString[i];
        newBit++;
    }

    string receivedText = encoder.GetString(tempByte);

    SetText(receivedText.ToString());
}
```

I'm well aware that my implementation using byteCount (which I use to traverse the byte array) is rather sloppy. When I step through the code, I find that when I get the error `byteCount == 1`, which is making strLen a negative number (since strLen is `byteCount - 3`, which is done because the packet contains a header, length, and CRC i.e. `byteCount - 3 == # of actual data bytes received`). This leads to by tempByte having a size of -2, which throws my exceptions. I, however, am having a very hard time figuring out why byteCount is being set to 1.

The code after this basically just traverses the data section of the array, copies it into the tempByte, then is sent off to a function to append the text in another thread.

Comment: Can you post the exact exception that you're getting?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in CP222_KAB_Lab04.exe

Additional information: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Comment: Hmya, you have a pretty serious problem.  You are using somebody else's software and it is screwing up your program badly by changing the processor configuration.  Clearly you, nor us, have any idea yet what dastardly software does that.  Right-click you EXE project, Properties, Build tab, change the "Platform target" setting to x64.  Now your program will crash with a BadImageFormatException and you'll now what number to dial on your phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that `byteCount` is 1 because you only received one byte - or rather, you processed the first byte before the second one arrived in the buffer.

The `ReadByte` function will wait for a certain amount of time for a byte to arrive if there isn't one waiting.

Maybe if instead of checking `BytesToRead`, you did something more like this:

```
byte headerByte = serialPort1.ReadByte();
byte length = serialPort1.ReadByte();
receivedString = new byte[length];
receivedString[0] = headerByte;
receivedString[1] = length;
for (int i = 2; i < length; i++) {
    receivedString[i] = serialPort1.ReadByte();
}
```

Comment: Wow, that works and it's so much cleaner. Thank you very much!